# Sort in R studio in ascending and descending

Tags: r, sorting

I need to sort the first half of the numbers in ascending order;
and the other half in the descending order in R-Studio

Please excuse me if I messed in posting this. please suggest the correction

```
mark = floor(seq(1,10))
print(mark)

sort(mark, 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Data
mark = floor(seq(1,10))
print(mark)
#Code
mark2 <- c(sort(mark[1:5]),sort(mark[6:10],decreasing = T))
```

Output:

```
mark2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 10  9  8  7  6
```

Another way can be:

```
#Code2
mark2 <- c(sort(mark[1:floor(quantile(mark,0.5))]),sort(mark[(floor(quantile(mark,0.5))+1):length(mark)],decreasing = T))
```

Output:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 10  9  8  7  6
```

Or more automatic:

```
#Code 3
mark2 <-c(sort(mark[1:floor(quantile(1:length(mark),0.5))]),
  sort(mark[(floor(quantile(1:length(mark),0.5))+1):length(mark)],decreasing = T))
```

Output:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 10  9  8  7  6
```